# How do I install Windows 7 64-bit on a Mac using Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, mac, 64-bit, boot-camp

Has anyone been able to install Windows 7 x64 under Bootcamp on a Mac?  I was able to get the 32-bit version to install, but I cannot get x64 to install.  The Mac doesn't seem to even want to boot the DVD.  And even if I get it installed are there drivers that will work with it?

I'd prefer to have Windows 7 x64 because I'd like to use the entire 6GB RAM in my MacBook Pro.

I'd appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: It worked right away for me.

Comment: you can download the Windows 7 x64 Bit from My Digital Life http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-iso-x86-and-x64-official-direct-download-links-ultimate-professional-and-home-premium/.

Comment: Related from Apple: [Boot Camp: Macs that work with 64-bit editions of Microsoft Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1846)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up [a blog post about how I got this to work](http://www.logicalvue.com/blog/2009/10/installing-window-7-x64-on-a-macbook-pro-using-bootcamp/):

> Note that you’ll need to do this from a Windows machine. I did it from
>   a Windows Vista VM in VMware Fusion.
>
> - Create 3 folders `c:\efi-iso`, `c:\efi-exe` and `c:\efi-dvd`
> - Download [oscdimg.exe](http://sergiomcfly.googlepages.com/oscdimg.exe) and put into `c:\efi-exe`
> - Unzip the Windows 7 ISO to `c:\efi-dvd` (7zip works great for this)
> - Open a Command window
> - Type: `cd c\:efi-exe`
> - Type: `oscdimg -n -m -bc:\efi-dvd\boot\etfsboot.com c:\efi-dvd
>     c:\efi-isowin7x64.iso`
>
> You’ll now have a new iso file in `c:\efi-iso`. Burn this iso to a DVD
>   (I used Toast back in OS X).
>
> This new DVD will boot just fine. From it you can install Windows 7 on
>   your MacBook Pro. But it doesn’t end there! You’ll want to install the
>   new Snow Leopard drivers, so after everything has finished, insert
>   your Snow Leopard DVD. This is where I ran into another problem. I
>   could not run the Setup. It would tell me that “this model Macintosh
>   does not support 64-bit drivers”.
>
> Again, after a little research, I found the solution. The trick is to
>   run the Snow Leopard Driver installer in compatibility mode:
>
> - On the BootCamp CD open “Drivers/Apple”
> - Right click on “BootCamp64.msi” -> Properties
> - Go To “Compability” Tab, under “Compability Mode” check the box and
>     select “Previous Versions of Windows”
> - Now doubleclick on the “BootCamp64.msi” and install normally
> - After doing this, the drivers all installed and everything seems to
>     be working great.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the RC and RTM on my 2009 MBP.  The standard instructions worked for installing.  Snow Leopard includes a new version of the Boot Camp drivers, but the last time I installed Win7 I had to run each installer seperately inside the driver directory on the SL disc.  I would get an error if I tried to run the regular BC installer.

Answer (score 1):

The installation is the same for the 64-bit as the 32-bit WIndows 7.

You need to install Boot Camp 3.0 after the installation of Windows and the subsequent updates 3.1 (x64 version), 3.2 (x64 version) and 3.3 (no difference for x64 and x32 versions). The updates are available on [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp).

I installed Windows 7 x64 on my MacBook Pro early 2008 (Mac OS 10.6.8) (although I have problems: slow computer, 'Not Responding' message appearing repeatedly, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get Windows 7 RC x64 working on my standard white MacBook - so I'm sure it can be done on your MBP. As far as I can recall I followed the instructions on this site and it seemed to work ok:

http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/01/15/using-boot-camp-to-install-windows-7-on-your-mac-the-complete-walkthrough/

Make sure you've got the latest edition of Bootcamp. The Vista Bootcamp drivers seem to work fine on Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

To install Boot Camp on a 64bit installation of Windows 7, look for `bootcamp64.msi` on the Leopard disk, right click, Properties, Compatability Mode, check the box "Run under previous Windows versions".

This worked a charm, as I was always getting the error: "This is not compatible … "