# Will Windows 7 run on a mid-2009 MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macbook, boot-camp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install 64-bit Windows 7 on Mac Using Bootcamp](https://superuser.com/questions/20646/install-64-bit-windows-7-on-mac-using-bootcamp)

Can I use BootCamp to run Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro? Are all the devices supported, like webcam and Apple's SSD?

The MBP in question is a mid-2009 revision model, with the 128GB Apple SSD and a non-replaceable battery.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate. Windows Vista and 7 are both supported on Bootcamp and this has been discussed on SU before. Also if 64Bit works there is no doubt 32Bit will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any reason to believe it won't?

If Vista worked properly, I would bet Windows 7 will work just as well.

Since your model is so recent, I have no reason to believe it won't

Comment: I was looking for a "yes it will and everything's supported" answer. I have not tried Vista though I believe that was supported.